# Does RDFlib available for micropython?

Tags: micropython, rdflib

If **RDFlib** is not available for **Micropython**, is there any other library available for Micropython to **work with RDF**?

Comment: I'm not seeing one either. What are you trying to do? Maybe there is a different approach we can recommend.

Comment: I want to create an RDF store in a Pycom sensor using Micropython. First Sensor data need to be gathered and then store them in the store as RDF data. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Usually in IoT you send pretty raw data to the cloud to do well formatted storage and presentation. 

Is there a specific reason to store the data on the device other than for a local cache?

Comment: And why RDF specifically? Here are some MP Storage libraries https://awesome-micropython.com/#storage

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
My project is a Semantic Web related project. For that, I need the data in RDF on the device then work on that RDF data.

Comment: I suggest using simpler data storage than RDF graphs on your devices and transforming our to RDF as needed. If you have a limited set of known classes and properties you need to record information according to, you could go even simpler than JSON and just use CSV! Then convert to/from RDF using pyTARQL - https://github.com/rdflib/pytarql

Comment: Thank you for your support. Problem is that RDFLib is not available for Micropython. It has many classes, so that I can't put it in Lib folder of Pycom sensor. Since pyTARQL is using RDFLib, I cannot use it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It appears there is no RDF library for MicroPython.

There are links on the top of the [Awesome MIcropython page](https://awesome-micropython.com/#libraries) to search all the usual places and none came up with a result for MicroPython + RDF. :-(

Since RDF is a set of rules to follow and can be represented in as [JSON-LD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-LD). Manually implementing RDF in JSON would be my suggestion as a path to explore. You would then use the JSON library builtin to MicroPython.

Since you mentioned Pycom, keep in mind, you're using their port of MicroPython and should look to their documentation and forums for additional help.